# Trying to access id3 tags of mp3 songs from a folder using a loop

Tags: python, directory, eyed3

I am trying to access the metadata of all mp3 songs in a folder. I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 Virtualbox and eyed3 0.6.18-1 with a shared folder between windows and ubuntu. I tried the following:

```
import os
import eyeD3

for root, dir, files in os.walk("home/undead/ShareWindowsTest")":
   for file in files:
      if file.endswith(".mp3"):
          audiofile = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(file)
          print audiofile.tag.getTitle()
```

Which is supposed print the title of each song in the folder. However this does not work. I tried using

```
if eyed3.isMp3File(file):
```

But still no luck. The error is specifically in the audiofile=... line where "file" seems to be a string and not an mp3 file, thus not being a proper input argument. I'm really new to this and would appreciate some help.

Comment: You are telling us what you think the error means, but then you say you don't understand it. You should also copy the full error message.

Comment: /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/undead/PycharmProjects/KavTest/Test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
 File "/home/undead/PycharmProjects/KavTest/Test1.py", line 25, in <module>
    audiofile = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(file)
  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eyeD3/tag.py", line 1653, in __init__
    
f = file(self.fileName, "rb");

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '01 California Dreaming (copy).mp3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you typed the full error message the error is clear:

```
No such file or directory: '01 California Dreaming (copy).mp3'
```

That means that the call is correct but the file name you are using does not exist. You are thinking: "but it came from `os.walk()` so it must exist!". Well yes, but `os.walk()` returns a list of tuples, each of three values: `root, dirs, files`. The `files` list of names are the filenames in the `root` directory.

Solution: you have to concatenate the `root` and `file` names:

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk("home/undead/ShareWindowsTest")":
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        audiofile = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(path)
```

PS: Are you missing a leading `/` in your `os.walk("/home...)`?

Comment: This has corrected the error. Would it be correct to say that by adding the path... line that it linked "file" to the actual file it was pointing to? Also Thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome! But I don't think so, _linking_ has a different, specific meaning when talking about files (see _hard link_ or _symbolic link_ for details). In your program `root`, `file` and `path` are strings of text that contain names (or part of names) of the file you want. You can say that `path` _refer_ to the actual file, or that it _contains_ the name of the file, or even that it points to the file.

Comment: Naturally `file` also contains the name of the file, but it didn't work, because that name is relative to `root`, and when you use a relative name as a filename, it is always interpreted as relative to the _current working directory_ (CWD). So unless your CWD equals `root` it will not work. By joining `root` plus `file` you make `path` either an absolute name or a name relative to the actual CWD, depending on what you passed to `os.walk()`.